# Type validation within stored procedures - oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, types, package

How does oracle stored procedures handle two different types with the same exact type declaration only that they are stored in two different packages?
Example:
package1 has type,

```
Type myType Is Table Of VARCHAR2(40) Index By Binary_Integer;
```

package2 has type,

```
Type myType Is Table Of VARCHAR2(40) Index By Binary_Integer;
```

Now if I use a stored procedure  (parameter => myType) stored in package2 and make the call in package1 (input => myType), this throws me an error

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
```

Does oracle handle these as different with no internal check for whether both types are 'table of varchar(40)'?

Also what's the best way I can make package1 myType be referencing package2 myType. Subtypes? or is there a way to do it directly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not matter if the type signatures are identical, `package1.mytype` will never be the same type as `package2.mytype` as they are declared in two different places so they are not identical.

If you want to pass types between packages then only declare the type in one place and use it in all the different packages.

For example:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package1
AS
  Type myType Is Table Of VARCHAR2(40) Index By Binary_Integer;
  
  PROCEDURE proc(
    value IN package1.mytype
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package1
AS
  PROCEDURE proc(
    value IN package1.mytype
  )
  IS
    i PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Package 1:');
    i := value.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ': ' || value(i) );
      i := value.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

Do not declare the type in `package2`, use the type from `package1`:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package2
AS
  PROCEDURE proc(
    value IN package1.mytype
  );
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY package2
AS
  PROCEDURE proc(
    value IN package1.mytype
  )
  IS
    i PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Package 2:');
    i := value.FIRST;
    WHILE i IS NOT NULL LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( i || ': ' || value(i) );
      i := value.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  value PACKAGE1.MYTYPE;
BEGIN
  value(2) := 'ABC';
  value(4) := 'DEF';
  value(5) := 'GHI';
  value(9) := 'JKL';
  
  PACKAGE1.PROC(value);
  PACKAGE2.PROC(value);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Package 1:
> 2: ABC
> 4: DEF
> 5: GHI
> 9: JKL
> Package 2:
> 2: ABC
> 4: DEF
> 5: GHI
> 9: JKL
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=da4ac00a7850c02cb29305ebb12030fe)*

---

> Does oracle handle these as different with no internal check for whether both types are 'table of varchar(40)'?

Yes, `package1 != package2` therefore `package1.mytype != package2.mytype` regardless of whether the signature of `package1.mytype` is identical to the signature of `package2.mytype`.

---

> what's the best way I can make `package1.myType` be referencing `package2.myType`. Subtypes? or is there a way to do it directly?

It will not work. Just create a single type and use that throughout all the packages.

Comment: Yea this makes the best sense. Unfortunately, a lot of our packages are using the package specific data types which makes it impossible to use its functions and procedures. One work around is subtypes,
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_plsql_user_defined_subtypes.htm
"Unconstrained subtypes on the other hand is a mere change of name for the base type to enhance the readability and flexibility in the applications."
Thanks for the info.

Comment: @user010101 You can create helper functions to copy the data from one type to another [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3a2cd8f0a4d4e0a92269adeb4b9b0e7b); however, its probably better to design the system properly in the first place to define types in a single place and reuse them rather than having multiple types with the same signature.

Comment: @MTO yea helper functions would be nice. Probably would be better than using subtypes tbh. but a little harder to implement with so many constrained user defined data types in the schema.